# Tempi semplici o composti con "dopo che"?

Tags: grammar

È corretto usare i tempi semplici oppure invece prevalgono i tempi composti con "dopo che"?

Esempio:

"Dopo un'ora che camminava/aveva camminato non ce la faceva più"

"Un'ora dopo che camminava/che aveva camminato non ce la faceva più"

"Dopo che fa/che ha fatto colazione, se ne va"

Potreste darmi una mano?

Comment: La distinzione non è tra tempi semplici o tempi composti, ma riguarda la *consecutio temporum* nelle subordinate italiane. Se ho tempo cercherò di preparare una risposta oggi pomeriggio, a patto che nessuno mi batta prima :)

Comment: Sarebbe molto più idiomatico dire “dopo aver camminato per un'ora non ce la faceva più” e “fatta colazione, se ne va”.

Answer (score 2):

Come ho scritto nei commenti, la distinzione non è tra i tempi semplici e tempi composti. Le regole per la scelta del tempo nelle subordinate vanno sotto il nome di *consecutio temporum* (dal latino "successione dei tempi"). Per questa risposta mi concentrerò nel caso di subordinate *all'indicativo* che esprimono *anteriorità*.

Secondo la grammatica italiana di Serianni (XIV.55), la regola dice che, per esprimere l'anteriorità:

- Si usano l'*imperfetto*, il *passato remoto*, il *passato prossimo* e il *trapassato prossimo* e *remoto* se la principale è al **presente** o al **futuro**;
- Si usano il *passato prossimo* e il *trapassato prossimo* e *remoto* se la principale è al **passato**.

Da notare che l'uso del *trapassato remoto* è corrente nell'italiano contemporaneo esclusivamente nelle proposizioni temporali (come quelle introdotte da *dopo che*) (*Serianni*, XIV.187).

La scelta del tempo tra le varie proposte del prospetto precedente dipende dall'autore e dà semplicemente una sfumatura semantica (per esempio una subordinata al trapassato prossimo darà un senso di anteriorità più marcato che una al passato prossimo).

---

Vediamo ora le tre frasi della domanda (leggermente parafrasate per renderle più idiomatiche):

> Dopo che camminava/aveva camminato per un'ora, non ce la faceva più.

In questo caso la principale è ad un tempo passato (*faceva*, all'imperfetto), l'imperfetto nella subordinata non è accettabile per cui dobbiamo scegliere **aveva camminato**.

> Un'ora dopo che camminava/aveva camminato non ce la faceva più

Questo caso è completamente analogo al precedente, per cui anche qui la forma corretta è **aveva camminato**.

> Dopo che fa/ha fatto colazione, se ne va.

### Qui la principale è al presente, per cui per indicare l'anteriorità va utilizzato il passato prossimo e non il presente: **ha fatto**.

Finalmente, come dice giustamente egreg nei commenti, la costruzione esplicita è un po' meno idiomatica quando la subordinata ha lo stesso soggetto della principale. Ad esempio, in *Serianni*, XIV.36.b: "Quando si ha identità di soggetto — grammaticale o logico — il costrutto esplicito è meno comune dell’implicito".

Quindi una versione più idiomatica delle frasi sarebbe:

> Dopo aver camminato per un'ora non ce la faceva più.
>   Un'ora dopo aver camminato non ce la faceva più.
>   Dopo aver fatto colazione se ne va.

Comment: Serianni è d’accordo con me! 

Comment: @Denis Nardin: non c'è nessun contesto in cui si potrebbe iniziare una frase come "dopo un'ora che camminava" o qualsiasi altro verbo all'imperfetto indicativo? .   Sento spesso usare l'imperfetto indicativo dopo questa costruzione frasale!  Ieri ho sentito questa frase " dopo un'ora che parlava, si faceva prendere dal panico". La frase in sé risulta stupida, ma vorrei sapere se rientra nelle norme grammaticali per esprimere contemporaneità tra due azioni.

Comment: @Nakamura A me suona un po' strana (la scelta dei tempi implica che le azioni siano contemporanee, ma semanticamente non ha molto senso). L'imperfetto in particolare indica la contemporaneità quando la principale è ad un tempo passato. Potresti dare qualche esempio in contesto?

Comment: "Ho conosciuto una persona molto strana! Costui, solitamente,  dopo un'ora che parlava si faceva prendere dal nervosismo"  Ora non so se possa andar bene, però magari c'è la possibilità di inserire un doppio tempo semplice, uno in subordinata e uno in quella principale. Mi pare che la frase " dopo che che FA colazione, se ne VA" sia corretta. Magari usando un tempo semplice al passato, magari in quest'ultima frase,  cambia.  Non saprei, davvero...

Comment: @Nakamura Onestamente a me suona molto informale (decisamente meglio "dopo che ha mangiato, se ne va" o meglio ancora "dopo [aver] mangiato se ne va"). È possibile che sia tipico di un registro colloquiale ma una ricerca nelle varie grammatiche cui ho accesso, ivi comprese alcune che registrano spesso anche gli usi colloquiali, non ha sortito alcun frutto.

Comment: @ Denis Nardin: "dopo che fa colazione, se ne va" risulta contemporaneo e accettabile, come mi hai detto tu, e in questo caso il verbo della subordinata al presente indicativo può alternarsi col passato prossimo, che sarebbe "dopo aver fatto colazione, se ne va"... Volendo descrivere qualcosa di abitudinale( una vecchia abitudine), non si potrebbe usare l'imperfetto indicativo anche nella subordinata?  Ti riporto lo stesso esempio di prima ma all'imperfetto :" Dopo che faceva colazione, se ne andava. Ma adesso ha perso questa abitudine." Attendo una tua risposta e ti ringrazio per la pazienza.

Comment: @Nakamura Onestamente quella parte della risposta è quella di cui sono più incerto, e per cui non sono riuscito a trovare alcuna citazione autorevole. Difatti sono mezzo tentato di rimuoverla. Adesso provo a dormirci un po' su e domani vediamo

Comment: @Denis Nardin: grazie mille, davvero  :D

Comment: @Nakamura Alla fine ho deciso di eliminare quella sezione perché non riuscivo a trovare una referenza decente e più me la ripetevo, più mi sembrava sbagliata.